# How can I update state while preserving immutability?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm not using the immutable library and I'm working on it.

I want to update the key and value values ​​of mapTable without changing the constant of PRICE_OPTION2_STATE.

I'd appreciate it if you could tell me how.
I have posted the results of the problem and the results I want.

```
//my code
tableData['option2Price'] = 50000;

const mapCopy = { ...copyState };
let tableCopy = { ...mapCopy[currentTableIndex].mapTable[findTableIndex] };
tableCopy = tableData;
mapCopy.tableCopy = tableCopy;

// problem
console.log(PRICE_OPTION2_STATE);


// initstate
const PRICE_OPTION2_STATE = [
  {
    id: 1,
    option2Name: '', 
    option2LeftSelect: 'sell',
    mapTable: [
      {
        tableId: 1,
        flag: true,
        option2Value: '', 
        option2Price: '', 
        discountInput2: '', 
        discountOption2: 'won', 
        option2Payment: '', 
        option2Tax: '', 
        option2settlementAmount: '', 
        option2RightSelect: 'sell', 
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

PRICE_OPTION2_STATE => problem console result

```
[
  {
    id: 1,
    option2Name: '', 
    option2LeftSelect: 'sell',
    mapTable: [
      {
        tableId: 1,
        flag: true,
        option2Value: '', 
        option2Price: '', 
        discountInput2: '', 
        discountOption2: 'won', 
        option2Payment: '50000', 
        option2Tax: '', 
        option2settlementAmount: '', 
        option2RightSelect: 'sell', 
      },
    ],
  },
]
```

result i want

```
[
  {
    id: 1,
    option2Name: '', 
    option2LeftSelect: 'sell',
    mapTable: [
      {
        tableId: 1,
        flag: true,
        option2Value: '', 
        option2Price: '', 
        discountInput2: '', 
        discountOption2: 'won', 
        option2Payment: '', 
        option2Tax: '', 
        option2settlementAmount: '', 
        option2RightSelect: 'sell', 
      },
    ],
  },
]
```

Comment: What are tableData, copyState, currentTableIndex, and findTableIndex?

Comment: The data to get when inputting option2Price input is tableData.

copyState is data obtained by deep copying PRICE_OPTION2_STATE.

currentTableIndex is {id, option2Name, mapTable } data.

findTableIndex is the index of mapTable.

Comment: It is data that increases as an array and the value of the mapTable array in the array also increases, and the index of the array can be changed. In addition, the index of the mapTable array can also be changed.

That's why you need to create an index separately.

Comment: *"copyState is data obtained by deep copying PRICE_OPTION2_STATE"* If that were true, then the code you presented could never mutate `PRICE_OPTION2_STATE`. So `copyState` is *not* a deep copy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll assume `copyState` is a reference to `PRICE_OPTION2_STATE` or at least is some sort of (shallow) copy of it. So to copy it, you should:

- not use object spread notation at the top level, since it is an array.
- not leave it at a shallow copy, but copy it *deeply*. So you'll also need to map the inner array and copy the objects it has.

Here is some inspiration:

```
// Assuming copyState has the structure of PRICE_OPTION2_STATE
// Get a deep copy
const mapCopy = copyState.map(({mapTable, ...rest}) => ({
    ...rest,
    mapTable: mapTable.map(obj => ({...obj}))
}));

// Now this assignment will not impact copyState / PRICE_OPTION2_STATE
mapCopy[currentTableIndex].mapTable[findTableIndex] = tableCopy;
```